# fileObj.getName() returns AbsolutePath path in Production env

Tags: java, linux

I came across the interesting issue with file object, here is detail

File (C:\Users\raj\Desktop\xyz.zip) is uploading from windows system to linux weblogic server.

At Server side, create file object the absolute path and get the file name by calling fileObj.getName() to create the folder in temp location to perform stuff.

fileObj.getName() returning Absolute Path path(C:\Users\raj\Desktop\xyz.zip) in linux server in production env, but the strange thing is when we are tested in our test bench it work as expected like xyz.zip

Can anybody let us know what are the possible reasons to return the absolute path ?

```
String tmpDir = "/share/folder/linux";
    String userSelectedFile = localDeployInterfaceForm.getFileName(); // getting the file absolute name as C:\Users\raj\Desktop\xyz.zip when user uploading to server

    File userSelectedFileObj = new File(userSelectedFile); // file object is created to get the file name as xyz.zip

    File newTmpFileToCreate = new File(tmpDir, userSelectedFileObj.getName()); // creating temp file as tmpfolder+xyz.zip

    /* Get the Absolure path for temprory file */
    String newTmpFilePath = newTmpFileToCreate.getAbsolutePath(); // expectation is /share/folder/linux/xyz.zip but actual result is /share/folder/linux/C:\Users\raj\Desktop\xyz.zip
```

Thanks
Dhorrairaajj

Comment: what is the absolute Path in linux server?

Comment: If you use Java 7+, you should use java.nio.file instead of File

Comment: Please provide code, and details of both environments

Comment: Is your test bench a windows environment? If so is suspect the problem is the backslashes in the path not being recognized as separaters on the production Linux environment.

Comment: test bench is linux and development env is windows, in test bench linux scenario is passed